# IIS server not reading JSON file, MIME map issue

Tags: json

I want to run JSOn file locally, but unable to run the file. Showing MIME map issue when try to access the file, where as js file run.

Plz help me o run JSON file on local drive.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : 'http://172.16.9.156/w/myTutorials.json',
  dataType : 'json',
  contentType : 'application/json',
  success: function (response) {   
   obj = JSON.parse(text);   
   document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
  },
  error : function(response){
   console.log(response);
   alert('error');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: running in asp.net / php?

Comment: running on local machine without asp.net / php, I have created local host with help of IIS, when I tried to load the "http://172.16.9.156/w/myTutorials.json" file in the browser it's not running where as all other files are running well.